# indentation configuration only for some files

Tags: git

I want to use

```
git config core.whitespace tab-in-indent,tabwidth=4
```

I want to have these settings for c++ files, so that I get warnings when there are wrong indentations when I use git diff. However, I have also Makefiles which need tabs. Is there a way to configure different whitespace settings for different files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) to tweak these settings.  Here's a snippet of my .gitattributes file:

```
*.c     text diff=cpp whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,tab-in-indent
*.cpp   text diff=cpp whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,tab-in-indent
*.h     text diff=cpp whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,tab-in-indent
*.hpp   text diff=cpp whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,tab-in-indent
*.py    text diff=python whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,tab-in-indent
*.tex   text diff=tex whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,tab-in-indent
*.java  text diff=java whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,tab-in-indent
*.pl    text diff=perl whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,tab-in-indent
*.php   text diff=php whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,tab-in-indent
*.rb    text diff=ruby whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,tab-in-indent

*.vcproj    eol=crlf
*.dsp       eol=crlf
*.dsw       eol=crlf

*.sh    eol=lf

*.jpg   binary
*.png   binary
*.gif   binary
*.tiff  binary
```

To adjust your whitespace settings, you could use something like:

```
*.ext   whitespace=tab-in-indent,tabwidth=4
```

The `*.ext` can point at paths, contain globs, etc.  It's  pretty flexible mechanism.

Comment: not sure if this is a function of time; but your file seems wrong.  shouldn't it be "whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,-indent-with-non-tab"....
would have been nice to include an example that did what user asked for.. yours seems pretty arbitrary. generic is nice, but it would be nicer to actually provide an answer that covered his use case....

Comment: I guess I was focused an the real question: "Is there a way to configure different whitespace settings for different files?"  And yes, it did work at one point.  I'll at least fix that part up.

Comment: Agreed ( which is why I upvoted before I commented ); you covered the broader question; however it afforded little improvment over the man page itself. It didn't cover a key piece that the man page example never demonstrated and which sadly seems to be different in every example I've read... which is the non-newline portion of the whitespace settings... I spent a great deal of time yesterday searching for actual working usage of that part and ultimately fig'd it out myself. The documentation for the existence of git attrib's is good but its usage, less so.

Comment: You can check which rules are applied with: `git check-attr --all -- <path>`. `<path>` does not need to be an existing file.

Comment: Setting `text` is unnecessary for these files, unless they use an exotic encoding format (but then you'll have other issues).

Comment: For files using the exact same settings, you can use a macro:
`[attr]cpp    diff=cpp whitespace=trailing-space,tab-in-indent` There is no conflict with the `diff=cpp`.

Comment: @Farway it may be unnecessary, but I generally prefer being explicit than implicit.  Especially since default behaviors change sometimes. :-)   Thanks for the information on attribute macros.  It's been quite a while since I looked through the docs and didn't realize Git grew that new mechanism.  The only downside I see with them is that if they're defined in outside of the top-level .gitattributes file, then you run the risk that other people cloning won't have the necessary settings.  Definitely good to know about though!

Answer (score 4):

Some additions to the answers by [John Szakmeister](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13823013/2504346) and [UpAndAdam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32235112/2504346).

To set file-specific rules you'll have to add a `.gitattributes` file in the root of you project. [docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)
(If you do not want it to be version controlled you can add it as: `.git/info/attributes`.)

```
# Macro's
[attr]cpp       diff=cpp whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,indent-with-non-tab,tabwidth=4
[attr]makefile  whitespace=trailing-space,indent-with-non-tab,space-before-tab,tabwidth=4

*.[ch]        cpp
*.[ch]pp      cpp
makefile      makefile
s.makefile    makefile
```

- Match files using the syntax for [.gitignore files](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format). i.e. `*` matches everything and `[ch]` matches both characters `c` and `h`.
- The `whitespace` option lists things to warn for.

  - Setting the `tabwidth` in the `whitespace` option is used to determine when and how to replace the tab and space characters. (The default value is 8 characters.)
  - `tab-indent` considers indentation using tabs an error.
  - `indent-with-non-tab` warns here when 4 or more spaces are used at the start of a line. Note that indentation with 3 spaces is accepted!
    Add `space-before-tab` to catch spaces hidden before and between the tabs.
    Note that spaces following tab are
- *Aside*: `diff=cpp` enables smarter diffs for C and C++ files.
- *Aside 2*: `trailing-space` warns on trailing white space characters at the end-of-line and end-of-file.

#### Verify Rules

- To verify what rules from `.gitattributes` are applied use:

```
git check-attr --all -- <pathname>
```

*`<pathname>` does not have to be an existing file. (i.e. `some.cpp` works)*

- To test the `whitespace` rules:
  Create a dummy file matching the filename rule and call: `git diff`.

```
trailing space 
trailing tab    
  2 spaces
    4 spaces
    tab
     tab and space
    space and tab
        tab, space, tab
```

#### Usage

Issues are marked when calling `git diff` and checked/ fixed when calling `git -apply ---whitespace=[warn|error|fix]`.
Configure default behaviour of `git apply` with:

```
git config --[global|local] apply.whitespace [warn|error|fix]
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer some 4 years ago and now come back and still find it very informative! I've copied portion of your explanation into my `.gitattributes` as comment because it's so much useful.

Answer (score 2):

As jszakmeister updated from my comment, here's just a sub-section for what you asked about.

- No tab-in-indent allowed for .cpp/.hpp files
- Tab's allowed for Makefiles/makefiles and *.mk files
- No trailing spaces allowed in all
- tabwidth of 4 in all

Notice the usage of the `-` modifier in the 'makefile-ish' entries to say don't call tab-in-indent an error.

```
makefile text          whitespace=-tab-in-indent,trailing-space,tabwidth=4
Makefile text          whitespace=-tab-in-indent,trailing-space,tabwidth=4
*.mk     text          whitespace=-tab-in-indent,trailing-space,tabwidth=4
*.cpp    text diff=cpp whitespace=tab-in-indent,trailing-space,tabwidth=4
*.hpp    text diff=cpp whitespace=tab-in-indent,trailing-space,tabwidth=4
```