# Error in console fatal: cannot enforce both tab-in-indent and indent-with-non-tab

Tags: git

I get fatal: cannot enforce both tab-in-indent and indent-with-non-tab

error I get for all git commands like git branch, git checkout etc from intellij console.

I tried with git customizations and other git options from github but nothing worked

i/p: git branch
response --> fatal: cannot enforce both tab-in-indent and indent-with-non-tab

Comment: I would suggest to [configure indentation manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13819764/3894977). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means 2 conflicting options are set together:

`indent-with-non-tab`:  highlights a line that is indented with **spaces** instead of tabs while
`tab-in-indent` : highlights an **initial tab** indent as an error.

You can check your configuration using this command :
`git config core.whitespace`

This will give you result something like 
`indent-with-non-tab,tab-in-indent`

You need to decide which option you want to use (you can use only one of them either treat tab as error or space as error). Then update your git configuration accordingly.

For example :
`git config --global core.whitespace tab-in-indent`

Comment: When I tried ```git config core.whitespace``` it returned ```\ ```value. And then I issued ```git config --global core.whitespace --replace-all``` to set it to default value. Even after doing this it didn't solve my issue. I also tried specifying a value ```tab-in-indent``` but it didn't help either.

Incidentally. ```git bash``` is working fine. I am only having issues when I try using git features in ```intellij```.

Comment: As mentioned above, I only tried adding tab-in-indent value to ```core.whitespace``` configuration. After resetting to default, I tried adding ```indent-with-non-tab``` value by issuing following command: ```git config --global core.whitespace --add indent-with-non-tab```. Now it started working fine in Intellij. But as part of validation, when I check the value it returned ```tab-in-indent```. This part is confusing; ???why it is returning tab-in-indent even though I set for indent-with-non-tab???.

Comment: You don't need to use ```--add``` option . You should check with ```git config --get-all core.whitespace``` . This will return you ```--add``` from global  and ```tab-in-indent```  value of ```core.whitespace``` configuration from local git config .